# How can I get when the button is clicked?

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets

I use wxwidget with erlang.

```
init() ->
    Wx=wx:new(),
    F=wxFrame:new(Wx, -1, "Hello, World!"),
    Panel = wxPanel:new(F),
    wxButton:new(Panel, 12, [{label,"Default"}]),
    wxFrame:show(F).
```

If I click on the button nothing is doing, I want to do something, execute a function for example. How can I do that?

Thanks 
Best regards

Comment: Please be more clear about what you are looking for and we can try to help.

Comment: In my code, I have a button, if somebody click on the button, I want to execute something, a function for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example in the shell.

First, create a window with a button, which you have already:

```
1> Wx = wx:new().
{wx_ref,0,wx,[]}
2> Frame = wxFrame:new(wx:null(), -1, "Hello, World!").
{wx_ref,35,wxFrame,[]}
3> 
3> Panel = wxPanel:new(Frame).
{wx_ref,36,wxPanel,[]}
4> 
4> Button = wxButton:new(Panel, 12, [{label,"Default"}]).
{wx_ref,37,wxButton,[]}
```

Now you can register a callback. In this case I am just printing out the data passed to the callback:

```
5> wxButton:connect(Button, command_button_clicked, [{callback,
5>         fun(Evt, Obj) ->
5>             io:format("click~n  event = ~p~n  obj = ~p~n", [Evt, Obj])
5>             end
5>         }]).
ok
```

Display the window:

```
6> wxFrame:show(Frame).
true
7>
```

Now, when you click the button, you should see:

```
click
  event = {wx,12,
              {wx_ref,37,wxButton,[]},
              [],
              {wxCommand,command_button_clicked,[],0,0}}
  obj = {wx_ref,39,wxCommandEvent,[]}
7>
```

**Edit (notes concerning OTP):**

When you implement a more fully OTP style application with wx you may want to do something slightly different, because you don't want that fun hanging around. Instead you can have a message sent to you when the button is clicked. If you omit the 'callback' option to connect then the event will be delivered to the process that calls connect instead. So you could have done:

```
5> wxButton:connect(Button, command_button_clicked, []).
ok
```

If you do that, and click the button, your (shell in this case) process will receive a message:

```
7> receive Msg -> Msg after 0 -> timeout end.
{wx,12,
    {wx_ref,37,wxButton,[]},
    [],
    {wxCommand,command_button_clicked,[],0,0}}
8>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attached link explains how to handle events in general with wxWidgets but it also discusses wxbutton and its click event.  There is some sample code there as well.  Hope this helps.

[wxWidget Event Handling](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html)